# SHG conversion efficiency

Tags: laser, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics, laser-interaction

I worked with a (rather complicated) laser system which eventually was able to produce about $1\,W$ of pulsed laser power and selecting the output wavelength via optical cavity ($1,0\mu m -1,5\mu m$). The laser was focused on a BBO (thickness $\approx 3\, mm$) to obtain SHG signal. Type II phase matching was used. The conversion efficiency was below $1\%$ and that is a problem. Has anyone enough experience to tell me, what might be the cause of this (if it is somehow possible to tell anyways)?

I read that it should be quite easy to get about $30\%$. I don't know the exact pulse duration, could it be the case that it is too long?

Comment: First of all, ensure that the wavelengths are properly selected according to the phasematching condition. Secondly, if the pulse duration is too long, then there is cancellation over a cycle so the wave isn't created much. And if the pulse duration is too short, then too there is a problem, which I'm unable to recall right now.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: It seemed that phasematching was achieved. The intensity displayed the correct form when tilted. Do you by any chance have approximate numbers which pulse duration is acceptable or any threshold above which it will not work?